# Unity Get corners of camera in world space

Tags: c#, 2d, unity

I'm making a 2D game and i need to get the corners of the camera in world cordinates. Is this possible in unity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Unity allows  you to get the corners of the camera in world coordinates.

```
Camera camera;
// gets top-right coord
camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1,1,camera.nearClipPlane);
```

Please see the [Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html).